# windowed sinc filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter, window-functions, sinc

Hello i'm designing a low pass filter windowed sinc in matlab

```
Fs = 2048;
Fc = 250/Fs;  % 250hz
M=2048 % (to get a 4hz transition bandwidth) sig contains 200hz + 300hz sinusoids, i'm aiming at leaving only the 200hz

filt =sinc(2*Fc*((1:length(t))- M/2)).*(0.42-0.5*cos(2*pi*(1:length(t))/M)+0.08*cos(4*pi*(1:length(t))/M))';
filt(M/2)=2*pi*Fc;
fsig = sig .* filt;
```

i understand that the winsinc filter is applied by convolution in the freq domain, so it means a multiplication in the time domain, which i did, but i get an erroneous result, i get a 0 flat frequency everywhere in my frequency plot.
what's wrong?

[image]

doing a freqz(filt) i get this, it seems correct reponse
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is mistaken. LTI filters are applied via **convolution** in time domain and multiplication in frequency domain.

The confusion possibly happens about designing the filter vs applying it.

The windowed sinc filter impulse response is given by

$$ h[n] = w[n] h_i[n] ,$$

where $h_i[n]$ is the ideal (infinite length) sinc filter which corresponds to a brickwall lowpass type in your case. To approximate and taper that filter, you apply a window $w[n]$ of length $L$ to it by multiplication in time domain and its effect in the frequency domain is a convolution by the well known Fourier modulation theorem:

$$H(e^{j\omega}) =  W(e^{j\omega}) \star H_i(e^{j\omega}) $$

However, when the filter is applied on an input, the output equation in the time domain is

$$y[n] = h[n] \star x[n] ,$$

and the corresponding frequency domain equation is

$$Y(e^{j\omega}) = H(e^{j\omega}) X(e^{j\omega}).$$

So, rewrite your code base don this to get an expected result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is what I understand , FIR filters are used by convolution and IIR filters by recursion. And i have been using multiplication instead of convolution so i corrected and update my code 
First: normalize my flter filt = filt / sum(filt); then i use the convolution function in matlab then i compare it with filter function
fsig = conv(sig , filt,'same') ;
fsignoise = conv(signoise , filt,'same');

fsig =filter(filt,1,sig);
fsignoise =filter(filt,1,signoise);  
and here are my results : conv:  https://imgur.com/a/XYLTCGU   filt: https://imgur.com/a/JtGOmzO

Comment: as you can see there is a cut off frequency around by it doesnt filter the second frequency it only diminish its amplitude by a large factor

Comment: yes it can only diminish it as a practical filter. Only ideal filters would completely eliminate them.